# How can a directory which is created via adb shell be executable in Android app

Tags: android, adb

I has made a directory named abc via adb shell in /data/data/com.helloworld.new_munion_sdk_demo/files/ and com.helloworld.new_munion_sdk_demo is my app name.
I try to visit the files in abc in my app and I found no file can be read with a FileNotFoundException.

Because the dir made by shell is default belongs to user root, so I use **chown** and **chmod 700** to change its permission as follow:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjn7c.png)

The dir abc is seems just no different like other normal directories, but its very odd this dir is can not be executable in the app, thus files in dir abc can not be readable.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0lpH.png)

This snapshot is from Android Studio.

I'm using nexus 5 and rom 6.0.1 complied by aosp.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a directory to store files, you might want to look into this article on storage for android

[Android Developers: Saving Files](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

Your app has access to this folder in Internal storage, which will be created using your own code. 
The partition /data is reserved for the OS as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but this article may not resolve my confuse. Actually I know the right way to create files and dirs under an app internal storage. I notice this issue just I need to do some test on it, and I found something out of my expect. You are right that /data is reserved for os but /data/data/<app package name> is belongs to the app itself.